# Magento Sales Mode

Tags: magento2

`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository` how can i check the shipping method in this repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get shipping Method Info from `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository`. You have to use `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`.

You can get Order id from `ShipmentRepository` and  after that Get Order Shipping methof information using `OrderRepositoryInterface::get($orderId)`

#### Code

```
        $id = 1;
    /**
     * $this->shipmentRepository instead of \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository
     */
    $shipment =$this->shipmentRepository->get($id);
    $orderId = $shipment->getOrderId();
    if($orderId){
        /**
         * $this->orderRepository instance of \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
         */
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $shippingDescription = $order->getShippingDescription();
        $order->getShippingMethod();
        $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
    }
```